# How to delete values between an interval in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file named, "BlockIsland25.csv" with the columns Date, Longitude, Latitude, and Wind Speed. I created a code a while back that deletes values whose longitude is outside of the interval (-71,-70).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\\Users\\chz08006\\Documents\\Results1\\BlockIsland25.csv")
indexNames=df[(df['Longitude'] <= -71)|(df['Longitude']>=-70)].index
df.drop(indexNames,inplace=True)
df.to_csv(r"C:\\Users\\chz08006\\Documents\\Results1\\BlockIsland25.csv")
```

How would I modify this code to also remove values within another specific interval inside the interval? For example, how would I modify it to also remove longitudes between -70.8 and -70.7?

Here is my attempt, which gave me a blank csv sheet. Perhaps there were no values within the desired intervals. I'm not sure if it worked as intended.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\\Users\\chz08006\\Documents\\Results1\\BlockIsland25.csv")
indexNames=df[(df['Longitude'] <= -71)|(df['Longitude']>=-70)|df['Longitude'].between(-70.8,-70.7))].index
df.drop(indexNames,inplace=True)
df.to_csv(r"C:\\Users\\chz08006\\Documents\\Results1\\BlockIsland25.csv")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to split into two steps , we can add `~`

```
con1=(df['Longitude'] <= -71)|(df['Longitude']>=-70)
con2=df['Longitude'].between(-70.8,-70.7)
df[~(con1|con2)].to_csv()
```